# How to redirect unregistered users to a specific url when they try to checkout?

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to modify Opencart to work as follows.

*As visitor goes to checkout page and he's not logged in yet i want to redirect them to the register page.*

*If already registered keep the checkout proccess as default.*

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with logged if condition. You will need to find and replace following code in 3 php files.

**1) Find and Open following 3 Files:**

catalog/controller/common/header.php
catalog/controller/common/cart.php
catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php

**2) Find following code line:**

```
$data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true);
```

**3) then Replace following code instead of above code.**

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {          
 $data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('checkout/checkout', '', true);
} else {
 $data['checkout'] = $this->url->link('account/register', '', true);
}
```

& then check it.